# Static IP address on the Raspberry PI 3 in combined network

Tags: networking, static-ip, cluster

I building cluster computer with two Raspberry PI 3 where I have 1 internet router and one LAN switcher. Both Raspberry PI are connected to the switcher.

Internet router gateway is 192.168.1.1

LAN Switcher gives me gateway 192.168.137.1

I need setup one PI to 192.168.1.100

Second PI need to have 192.168.1.101

Now I stack on the `/etc/dhcpdcd.conf`

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.100
static routers=192.168.137.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.137.1
```

I also try something like this:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.100
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1
```

But this not gives me internet access and can't access to this PI.

Any help?

Comment: Your question is unclear (possibly a language issue) See [How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697) You can have only **ONE** gateway - post `ip r` output

Comment: if the pi's are "behind" the "LAN Switcher", they would need a 192.168.137.x address - and appropriate routing in other parts of your network would need to be set up so that the 192.168.1.x network knows how to "reach" the 192.168.137.x network

Comment: @Jaromanda I not understand what you tell me.

Comment: @Milliways I trying to setup static IP to PI but behind PI is switcher and internet router. Switcher and router have different gateway addresses

Comment: I don't know what a "LAN Switcher" is. You need to explain your setup. A switch should not have a gateway and there must only be a single DHCP server on a network. This is becoming more a problem about your network NOT the Pi. Unless you can post some meaningful data e.g. `ip r` no one can help.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the output of these two commands from one RasPi to it: `ip addr` and `ip route`.

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić - perhaps you need to learn basic networking in that case